# Proof that a set is a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ be a nonempty set with an associative operation and for each $a\in G$ exists only one $a'\in G$  such that $aa'a=a$. Prove that $G$ is a group.

I tried playing with the fact that $aa'a=a$ and the only thing I found is that $(a')'=a$. Then I tried proving that for each $a,b\in G$, $aa'=bb'$ (which means we can write $e=aa'$ and then $G$ has an identity) but I couldn't get anything meaningful.

Proof that $(a')'=a$ (by request):

$aa'a=a$
$a'aa'a=a'a$ (multiply by $a'$ from left side)
$a(a'aa')a=a(a')a$ (multiply by $a$ from right side)
We know that $a'$ is the only one that satisfy $aa'a=a$ and therfore $a'aa'=a'$ (whice means that $(a')'=a$.

Comment: Didn't try it yet, but did you try to find out what $(ab)'$ is? Maybe that helps.

Comment: Would you mind editing in your proof that $(a')' = a$?  I have having trouble simplifying the calculation...

Comment: Thanks!  it makes perfect sense, though I think you multiply on the *left* by a instead of the right

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, then this is false. Consider $G = \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{ 0 \}$ with addition.

Comment: @AJY addition is not closed on that set...

Comment: @verret Indeed! In fact, I was mistaken.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is true, unless I am misunderstanding something. Inverse semigroups have this property, but they are not all groups.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_semigroup

Answer (score 0):

This is definetely true. I attempted to prove it some time ago and I found it a bit tricky (and cool).

> *Hint: Suppose $e$ idempotent, $a\in G$. Consider $ae$. Then there is...*

*Note that it is necessary to show that such an idempotent do exist. You might also use the "lemma" you just showed (in the form of $a'=a'aa'$).*